# MySQl - Find Duplicates Cross Relational Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
`products`
----------
`product_id` (int)
`sku` (varchar=50)

`websites`
----------
`website_id` (int)

`website_products`
----------
`website_id` (int)
`product_id` (int)
```

I am trying to find **duplicates products based on the SKU per website**. This is my attempt so far, but pretty sure it's not working:

```
SELECT b.`website_id`, a.`product_id` ,COUNT(a.*) AS count
FROM `products` AS a 
     LEFT JOIN `website_products` AS b 
         ON ( a.`product_id` = b.`product_id` ) 
WHERE 1
GROUP BY a.`sku` 
HAVING count > 1
ORDER BY b.`website_id`
```

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: "pretty sure it's not working", what happens?

Comment: @Marcus the results I get seem to be VERY Off reporting something like 60 duplicates for many websites, which I'm 99% sure is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is that you are looking for. Perhaps with some sample data I can refine my query. With this you take all products for a SKU in a website (for SKUs with more than one product)

```
SELECT 
    b.`website_id`, a.sku, 
    group_concat(DISTINCT a.`product_id`) as sku_products 
FROM `products` AS a 
     LEFT JOIN `website_products` AS b 
         ON ( a.`product_id` = b.`product_id` ) 
GROUP BY b.`website_id`, a.`sku` 
HAVING count(distinct a.`product_id` ) > 1
ORDER BY b.`website_id`
```

Comment: Hi Danihp, didn't quite work, for instance, lets say there are two products (1, 123), (2, 123) (product_id and sku), if either one of them is on a website, I don't care. If both are on a website, I want to know (because they have the same SKU)

Comment: @ Danihp, I did, every website_id was NULL

Comment: @kerry, in order to find where is the mistake [I have wrote your query on data](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/121747/) you can test it. (SQLServer don't allow group_concat, I replace this aggregate function by MAX only for test pourposes)